# Is my machine 32 bit or 64 bit?

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, 32-bit

i know this question has been asked a lot on superuser, but i am stuck as i have checked with different applications, windows system information, vmware processor x64 processor utility, cpu-z, securable, registry entry..and i am getting different results.
i have windows 8 32-bit.

**windows system information**

System Type X86-based PC

**System Properties**

[image: system properties screenshot]

**vmware guest64check**

[image: vmware guest64check]

**cpu-z**

[image: cpuz]

**Securable**

[image]

Why am i getting different results in windows system info and vmware processor utility, and what exaclty is my machine type?
Will it be able to run windows 8 64-bit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your machine is x64bit. The System Properties is telling you that you are running 32bit Windows on a x64bit capable processor. The VMware x64bit check will only pass if you have a x64 bit capable processor with virtualization extensions which your processor doesn't. According to Intel's processor page for the T3100 Penryn processor, it states that it is capable of 64 bit processing. ([Intel Penryn Celeron M T3100 info page](http://ark.intel.com/products/37258/Intel-Celeron-Processor-T3100-1M-Cache-1_90-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)). You should be aware that you cannot upgrade from 32bit to 64bit Windows while keeping your applications intact, meaning that you will need to reinstall your programs after the upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

To run 64-bit guest on 32-bit host, you need a CPU that support either AMD-V or Intel VT. As it were, your CPU doesn't support Intel VT, but it did support EM64T AKA AMD64, which mean you can run 64-bit OS as a host.

Comment: @Nikhar check the BIOS settings for your computer you may be able to re-enable AMD-V or Intel VT as the secureable screen states that your CPU has the feature, but it is locked.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sadly T3100 don't have VT-x :( http://ark.intel.com/products/37258/Intel-Celeron-Processor-T3100-1M-Cache-1_90-GHz-800-MHz-FSB It was one of my grief at choosing low-end Intel for developing WP8 (although oddly the lowly Celeron 847 did support VT-x)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain i checked that but there is no option for virtualization

Comment: :( that is why I said may instead of will. Your only option now, if you want 64 bit guest OS's, is you must be running a 64 bit host OS, That will require a OS re-install.

Answer (score 3):

You, or whoever loaded windows for you, installed the 32 bit version of Windows 8 on your 64 bit compatible hardware.

You will need to re-install windows and use the 64 bit version of the installer if you want to use 64 bit programs (that is what the VMware check is complaining about). Your Windows license is good for both 32 bit and 64 bit so you should not need to buy any new licenses, just reinstall the OS.

Answer (score 1):

When all else fails, you can always look up the processor directly from the manufacturer website.  In this case, Intel, you can go to ark.intel.com and look up that processor. Yours is a 64-bit processor (look under instruction set)  So your machine is a 64 bit machine, but you are running a 32-bit version of windows,  I would upgrade to 64 bit, as it will not only run faster, but recognize more than 3.5 gigs of ram. [Your processor](http://ark.intel.com/products/37258/Intel-Celeron-Processor-T3100-1M-Cache-1_90-GHz-800-MHz-FSB?q=t31)

Comment: If the user has < 4GB RAM, how will it run faster then the 32 bit version?